# In azure blob storage container can I make the search functionality(folders) case insensitive

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

[image: In Azure blob storage ,I have bunch of folder and inside that I have some files. Is there way I can make the search functionality of the folder names case insensitive]

I have  bunch of folders in the blob container
Is there way I can make the search functionality of the folder names case insensitive ?
eg: if I have folder ABC ,if I type ab or AB in search box ABC folder should show up
Sorry new to Azure so ,thanks for any ideas or tips . Would like to use container as opposed to file share to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. In Azure blob storage, the name of folders and files is mixed case and case-sensitive. If you want to search the folders and files by lower case, you need to store them all in lower case.